# Python: Conditional column based on the lenght of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column with telephone numbers and I need to add another one that says which numbers may be correct based in their lenght. (Telephone number with more than 6 digits may be correct)

I've tried:

`df['correct number?'] = np.where(len(df['telephone']) > 6, 'Yes', 'No')`

But it returned Yes to all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len(df['telephone'])` is exactly equal to `len(df)` (why?). You want:

```
df['correct number?'] = np.where(df['telephone'].str.len() > 6, 'Yes', 'No')
```

or

```
df['correct number?'] = np.where(df['telephone'].apply(len) > 6, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: Maybe `len()` instead?